# How can I keep track of current user across my web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, routes

I'm trying to create a web app with similarities to a social media platform. My back-end is MongoDB (Mongoose), Express.js, and Node.js. For routing, I need to keep track of the current user's username, so that I could use an api route like example.com/username to get their personal profile. The problem is I don't have a way of knowing what the current user's username is. I've considered using cookies, but this seems very insecure (I could be wrong). I've also considered using sessions, but I've read that they aren't efficient and don't scale well. So how can I accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: how about using JWT? have you do research on it?

Comment: @DSPdav I thought JWT was just for authentication, but it can store the userID too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have done this is as follows:

1. Upon authentication I provide the user with a Bearer token which contains his/her userid.
2. The user has to provide this token in all subsequent authenticated requests.
3. Use middle-ware to verify the token and attach the user on the request.

Upon Login

```
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user.id.toString() }, 'secret')
user.tokens = user.tokens.concat( { token } )
await user.save()
```

Send this token with the response and also store in database.

In the Authentication Middleware do something like this

```
try {
    const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token,'secret')
    const user = await User.findOne({_id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token' :token})
    if(!user) {
        throw new Error()
    } 
    //attach the token and the user upon the request
    req.token = token
    req.user = user
    next()
} catch (e) {
    res.status(401).send({error : "Authentication Required"})
}
```

Comment: Oh I understand now. I didn't realize you could store a username in the token, but I guess it makes a lot of sense. Thanks